# Hide selected icons from the system tray permanently

Tags: windows-vista, notification-area

Is there a software that will allow me to hide some of the icons on my system tray? And by hide I don't mean the default Windows hide functionality. I want some of the icons to be permanently disabled from the system tray but i want the programs still running.

Comment: what OS?  *(obligatory characters to allow me to leave a comment.)*

Comment: oh sorry...windows vista (also simply fill the comment with spaces...it works and they dont appear on the comment afterwards)

Comment: hm apparently they fixed the bug :P forget it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[PS Tray Factory](http://www.pssoftlab.com/pstf_info.phtml)** can hide icons in the system tray.
It's not free though.

> PS Tray Factory allows you to:
>
> - restore system tray icons after Explorer.exe crash
> - change original tray icons with your own icons, more...
> - move low-activity icons from the system tray into the special menu,
> - quickly access hidden icons,
> - change the order of icons in the system tray (sort tray), more...,
> - hide seldom used system tray icons ,
> - protect the tray menu with password,
> - minimize any application to the system tray.