# How can I permanently hide icons in the notification area?

Tags: windows, notification-area

Is there any free way to permanently hide system icons (such as the wireless icon) in the notification area? Supposedly this can be done with `Customize Notifications`, but it doesn't stick on my machine.

[PS Tray Factory](http://www.pssoftlab.com/pstf%5Finfo.phtml) was mentioned [in another question here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/48671/hide-selected-icons-from-the-system-tray-permanently), but it's not free.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows hides icons based on their associated text.  If the text changes, Windows considers it to be a new icon with a different hide/show configuration.  Which is ridiculous.

Comment: Yeah, that is ridiculous. Fix it, MS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that certain apps don't provide a title for the system tray icons. Windows doesn't have a way of recognizing them if they don't have a title, so it doesn't remember the option to always hide. That's why certain icons just can't remember to stay hidden.

Answer (score 1):

[TraySaver](http://www.mlin.net/other.shtml)

> TraySaver alleviated these problems by
>   letting you stash away unneeded tray
>   icons in a hideable separate tray, and
>   by restoring the icons after an
>   Explorer crash. It also added an
>   option to the system menu of any
>   application that let you minimize it
>   to the tray.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try TweakXP
http://www.tweakxp.com/article36789.aspx

Comment: Hmm, that hides all of them. Not quite what I want.